# Run batch file remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, wmi

I have 200 laptops that I maintain - they are running a piece of software that employs SQL Replication - they all sync back to a central server - `a.b.com`

If one of them goes bad I need to execute some stored procedures on the SQL Server to re-initialise them, I want to script this so it can be done form the client machine.

On the SQL Server I have enabled `sqlcmd` and created a batch file that invokes the `.sql` file I want to execute.

I now need to be able to script the client side setup scripts so that it will run this batch file once it gets to a certain point - I have read this may be possible with WMI but I am not so sure as the server is at a URL and not actually part of the LAN.

I have tried connecting using `wmic /node:a.b.com printer list status` just to test but I get `invalid node`.

Is there a way using command line tools to do this?

Comment: What is the operating system on the targets? Have you thought about PowerShell? WMI certainly doesn't seem like the answer here.

Comment: @Aaron - The client OS is XP - Target OS is Server 2003 Standard - To be honest no I hadn't thought about PowerShell - I know very little about it - I really need to set up a client/server sort of connection over the internet with authentication - Telnet came to mind but I don't know if server 03 allows telnet control of cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet should work. If you don't have it enabled, this link shows how. http://www.petri.co.il/enable_telnet_on_windows_2003.htm

Comment: I have been looking around but can't find a way to get telnet to load command.COM?

Comment: @MylesGray Telnet sends your commands and input/output [in plain text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755017%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Be careful.